# How much of Java can I really use with GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'd like to learn GWT, and I like the fact that it compiles to Javascript. My question is, how much of Java I can really use with GWT? My guess would be that limitations apply mostly for client side, while on the server side I should be able to make use of any existing Java library, right? Or, will I be only able to use a small subset , because of the compilation to Javascript thing?

What are it's limitations? I am interested in what it's not able to do, or things that require too many workarounds to implement. I need to know if learning GWT is a good choice for a possible freelance carrier in web development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GWT website has [this documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) exactly to answer that question.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out there are absolutely no retrictions on what you can use server side. The GWT compiler will only process code intended for the client (specified by source package), leaving you free to use anything you'd like in the rest of your procject (server side, etc).

Comment: Good point. The OP already guessed that such is the case, but yes.

Answer (score 5):

See the [JRE emulation docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).  Those are the supported out of the box emulated classes that you can use.

"Google Web Toolkit includes a library that emulates a subset of the Java runtime library. The list below shows the set of JRE packages, types and methods that GWT can translate automatically. Note that in some cases, only a subset of methods is supported for a given type."

You can also provide your own emulation for other classes using `<super-source/>` in your gwt.xml to point to a package that will provide replacement Java classes for those that can't be directly compiled to JavaScript.